# how to check word similarity in python with considering the input order

Tags: python, comparison, similarity

Usually, similarity checks in the existing methods are in such a way that the comparison between two words always gives the same score. But I want to get another score, if the first input is changed with the second input.
I expect this in the code:

```
similarity("large bag cat", "large bag dog wild")  # score: 0.X
similarity("large bag dog wild", "large bag cat")  # score: 0.Y
```

It is possible that all the words of the first input are included in the second input, but only a few words of the second input are in the first input.
Algorithms like Levenstine.... Always display the same score.

Comment: And to what would the score change? How would you measure it?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal It is possible that all the words of the first input are included in the second input, but only a few words of the second input are in the first input.